# WinAPI: Handling the Left mouse double click for supressing the first click?

Tags: winapi

How can I handle left mouse double click events in Windows by suppressing the first click events.For ex: Left mouse single click highlights the image object and double click zooms the image, but for now I want on double click not to highlight the image object?

This happens probably the sequence of events triggered on left mouse double click are `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONUP`, `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`, and `WM_LBUTTONUP`. i.e it triggers the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, so how do I handle this?

Comment: This is a bad idea. Double-click handler should not suppress single click by design. You can do this with some time measurement tricks, but the program behaviour will look strange, because exact time measurement is impossible in handling Window messages.

Comment: GetDoubleClickTime function can help you to do want you want, but I stongly recommend you to change this design.

Comment: Thanks For your comments."because exact time measurement is impossible in handling Window messages"..........This part of your comment can you please elaborate to me.For my understanding please.

Answer (score 3):

You can't suppress the behavior.  What you can do is start a one-time timer on the first click, where the interval is set to number of milliseconds reported by `GetDoubleClickTime()`.  If a double click occurs, stop the timer and perform your double-click logic.  If the timer elapses, stop the timer and perform your single-click logic instead.